# creating a poly using the rows of a coeffient matrix//translating Matlab to Mathematica

Tags: interpolation, matlab

What I want to do is something similar to `polyval` in MatLab.

I have the MatLab coding,

```
polyval(SM(i,:),x_shift)
```

I know how to plot functions in Mathematica, I just need help converting this into Mathematica. `SM(i,:)` represents the ith row of the matrix SM, and the poly is evaluated at x_shift,

note: I don't want to use `interpolation`, I want to do the math behind it.

Comment: It would be better not to presume familiarity wit MatLab. Please explain what you want to achieve,  e.g. in terms of input and output examples, optimally in WL format.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own polyval ([reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html)), which creates a polynomial defined with coefficients `p` and evaluates it at values `x`.

```
polyval[q_, x_] := Total[Reverse[q] z^Range[0, Length[q] - 1]] /. z -> x
```

Usage (same example as from the Matlab documentation page).

```
polyval[{3, 2, 1}, {5, 7, 9}]
{86, 162, 262}
```

As with the Matlab function, `x` can be a scalar, vector, or matrix.

Comment: A slightly shorter form: `polyval[q_, x_] := q.z^Range[Length[q] - 1, 0, -1] /. z -> x`

Comment: for polynomials of higher order and large arrays in x using `HornerForm` before inserting `z` will be somewhat more efficient. I also think one should localize `z` (or use `\[FormalZ]` ), otherwise the code will break when `z` has a definition...

Comment: @AlbertRetey -- honestly, now that I have seen what polyval is, I can't imagine a use for it. In Mathematica, the idiomatic approach would be to define the polynomial q[x] as a symbolic polynomial and then simply evaluate it at the list of points x. I view Matlab's polyval as a workaround for the fact that it doesn't support representing polynomials in a symbolic way.

Comment: @bill: it certainly is true that it always is a good idea to embrace the specific strengths of a programming language and in this case that would be the symbolic nature of Mathematica which explains why such a function does not exist. I would even suggest to put an according note into your answer. But there might be cases where such a function can be justified, e.g. evaluation efficiency, import of coefficient-lists from some source or simplification of the translation of code from matlab. If it is used for whatever reason I think it would be justified to write it in a more robust way.